# SQLite Out Of Memory Exception while retrieving the data via Data Reader

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am having an SQLite database and I am trying to retrieve some 20 records from a Query. I am using SQLite v1.0.109.0 as per my build requirement

I am trying to retrieve the data via DataReader. The columns are of type Varchar. One of the column's (XmlDefinition) data length is 12115465 (I found using Length())

The code is working fine and retrieved some 10 rows, and while fetching the 11th row it throws a System.OutOfMemoryException while fetching the value for the XMLDefinition column with the below Stacktrace

```
at System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength, Encoding encoding) 
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count) 
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.UTF8ToString(IntPtr nativestring, Int32 nativestringlen) 
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.GetText(SQLiteStatement stmt, Int32 index) 
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetString(Int32 i) 
   at MyProject.GetResourceDefinition(IDataReader dataReader)
```

I am retrieving the data via DataReader using below method

```
public static T ExecuteReader<T>(string commandText, IEnumerable<QueryParameter> parameters, Func<IDataReader, T> parserMethod)
    {
        using (var command = SqliteDbProvider.FetchSqliteDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            AddQueryInCommand(commandText, parameters, command);
            using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                return parserMethod(dataReader );
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the parser method is going to retrieve the data from DataReader

```
private static IResourceDefinition GetResourceDefinition(IDataReader dataReader)
        {
            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(dataReader["ResourceDefinition"].ToString());
            string xmlDefiniton = dataReader["XmlDefinition"].ToString();
        }
```

I saw few people suggested to use [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() set to SequentialAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteReader_System_Data_CommandBehavior_) and to use **GetString(columnIndex)** instead of **dataReader["ColumnName"]**

But nothing helps, anyone, can help me with this.

Comment: Increase virtual memory which will use your disk as memory when you exceed the available memory : https://windowsreport.com/how-to-increase-virtual-memory-windows-11/?force_isolation=true

Comment: The application is deployed in 8000 sites, we could not request 8000 sites to change their System settings. Anything that can be fixed by code is recommended

Comment: Why are you now getting a memory exception if this is a working application?

Comment: We just deployed this, not all sites have large data in columns. Some already have and we have provisions for users to create datasets on their own, so they create data in a single attempt for their convenience. So this may happen in future

Comment: This is a design issue.  You didn't include memory size in your requirements and now looking for a fix.  You want virtual Memory and there is no such animal unless you either install more memory on the machines or increase you virtual memory.  Or you can redesign your queries to return the data in chunks so you do not exceed the memory.